# java equivalent to python for hashing

Tags: java, python, hash, hmac, hmacsha1

I have below code in java documentation (it takes `secret_key` and `data` as input) :

```
javax.crypto.Mac mac = javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1")
mac.init(new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(secret_key.getBytes(), "HmacSHA1"))
byte[] hexBytes = new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex().encode(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes()))
String signature = new String(hexBytes, "UTF-8")
```

after doing some RnD online , i wrote equivalent python  to :

```
decodedKey = secret_key.decode("hex")
hmac_val = hmac.new(decodedKey, data.encode('UTF-8'), hashlib.sha1)
signature = hmac_val.digest().encode('base64')
```

but on doing a post request with this signature value in header, i am getting

> ValueError: Invalid header value 'XXXXXXXXXX'

is my python equivalent correct? it would be great help if someone can explain!

**EDIT**

Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String secret_key = "c84766ca4a3ce52c3602bbf02ad1f7";
        String data = "some data";
        javax.crypto.Mac mac = javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        mac.init(new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(secret_key.getBytes(), "HmacSHA1"));
        byte[] hexBytes = new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex().encode(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes()));
        String signature = new String(hexBytes, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("signature : "+signature);
 }
```

**o/p**

```
signature : 2b565c0476eed0f350ddb3a2852a4cab91281bdc
```

**Python :**

```
In [1]: import hmac

In [2]: import hashlib

In [3]: secret_key = "c84766ca4a3ce52c3602bbf02ad1f7"

In [4]: data = "some data"

In [5]: decodedKey = secret_key.decode("hex")

In [6]: hmac_val = hmac.new(decodedKey, data.encode('UTF-8'), hashlib.sha1)

In [7]: signature = hmac_val.digest().encode('base64')

In [8]: signature
Out[8]: '3qE5SqSdvBEJcy8mSF+srqNXCd4=\n'

In [9]:
```

Comment: _to err is human to forgive divine_ :)

Comment: Post the actual output from the two.

Comment: My first guess is that the data you're hashing isn't represented identically on both platforms. Feed each one an identical pregenerated byte sequence.

Comment: @chrylis : added edit, please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referrring to this thread :

[Java method which can provide the same output as Python method for HMAC-SHA256 in Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947026/java-method-which-can-provide-the-same-output-as-python-method-for-hmac-sha256-i)

minor tweeking for `sha1`, below is simple equivalent :

```
In [13]: print hmac.new(secret_key, data, hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
2b565c0476eed0f350ddb3a2852a4cab91281bdc
```

Answer (score 0):

**pycrypto** has a hash function https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto

because of *ValueError: Invalid header value 'XXXXXXXXXX'* see this thread [ValueError: Invalid header value 'H2O Python client/2.7.9 (default, Apr 2 2015, 15:33:21) \n[GCC 4.9.2]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345675/valueerror-invalid-header-value-h2o-python-client-2-7-9-default-apr-2-2015)

maybe the header in your post is not compatible with the library you use for the post

what libraries do you import in the python code ?

Comment: to get the same result the algorithms have to be equal down to bit level (**endianness** and so on) normally you could use a debugger  (pdb, jdb) to step through each operation in the algorithm and see where the difference occurs. See this thread for the source code for javax.crypto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181023/javax-crypto-jdk-source-code-again (java is always big-endian afaik)

Comment: why would i use some other language in my program when the same feature is present in my language?

Answer (score 0):

if you want it easy try this: https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Hash.HMAC-module.html

maybe the encoding influences the result, [UTF-8] then [base-64]

Comment: getting `ec0e4e884b0056d817efb56ab5920509` as output, so not correct, also, why not edit existing answer rather than posting a new one?